# What is the difference between "export NEXT_ENVIRONMENT='development'; next dev" and "next dev" in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, scripting, environment-variables, package.json

I am using Next.js and I have seen this: `export NEXT_ENVIRONMENT='development'; next dev`

I understand the `next dev` part. What I do not understand is `export NEXT_ENVIRONMENT='development'`

What is the difference between `export NEXT_ENVIRONMENT='development'; next dev` and `next dev` in Next.js?

Comment: `export NEXT_ENVIRONMENT='development'` loads an environment variable `NEXT_ENVIRONMENT` with the value `'development'`, which can be accessed through `process.env.NEXT_ENVIRONMENT` in the Next.js app.

Comment: Oh I understand. Can it also be accessed in the front-end of the next-js app?

Comment: It can't. In Next.js, to be accessible on the client-side an environment variable needs to be prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser.